# Julia: print_with_color() in terminal

Tags: julia

If my script `run_this.jl` contains the following, single line of code:

```
print_with_color(:green, "Hello")
```

and I run the script in the terminal as `julia run_this.jl`, it does not print in color. Is there a way to make this function work when I run a julia script in the terminal?

Comment: `print_with_color` was deprecated in favour of `printstyled` in Julia 0.7 and removed altogether in Julia 1.0.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the color option when calling your julia script.  E.g.

```
julia --color=yes run_this.jl
```

That works for me on mac osx and linux.  Not sure about windows.

Comment: Any way to modify the juliarc.jl so I don't need to pass this every time?

Comment: @Cokes My understanding is that this was considered but rejected, as of now, by the development team (see [here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/13889)). Thus the suggestion instead was to define your own wrapper script for Julia if you wanted something like that.

Comment: ah, nice! Adding `alias julia='julia --color=yes'` to my `bashrc` does the trick! Thanks!