# How to enable color when using cmd or linux terminal on a file?

Tags: julia, terminal-color

How do I enable color in Julia when I am not using the REPL? When I try and run my Julia script on the Linux terminal it doesn't show colors.

Also another quick question. What's the best way to run a Julia script within another script? Right now, I just do `include("file.jl")` and add the arguments in the `ARGS` array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Julia: print\_with\_color() in terminal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37794641/julia-print-with-color-in-terminal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it by putting the following line at the top of my script:

```
Base.eval(:(have_color = true))
```

Answer (score 6):

Run your script with

```
julia --color=yes file.jl
```

In the future, you should only ask one question per question. But to answer your other question, I would refactor the script into a function and call that function instead. That seems like a more elegant approach than adding arguments to `ARGS`.